# expressions using body parts

Tags: expressions, nouns, word-usage

'Hands' of a clock,
'Arms' of a chair,
'Nose' of a plane,
'Mouth' of a river.
In these expressions human body parts are used.What are such expressions called?

Comment: personifications maybe

Comment: Generally, these are examples of [*metaphor*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/212174/the-definition-of-the-metaphor), but I don't know if there is a particular name for comparing objects to parts of the body.

Answer (score 3):

> **ANTHROPOMORPHIZE** *transitive verb*: to attribute human form or personality to things not human
>
> — **an•thro•po•mor•phi•za•tion** -ˌmȯr-fə-ˈzā-shən\ *noun*
>
> [**MERRIAM-WEBSTER DICTIONARY *online***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/anthropomorphize)

Comment: or, as an adjective, "anthropomorphic"

Comment: Yes, @BrianHitchcock - or anthropomorphizations, it's all there.

Comment: anthropomorphism "the attribution of human characteristics or behaviour to a god, animal, or object." [OD](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/anthropomorphism) >Chairs have arms, tables have legs, the bed has a foot, and the needle has an eye--all of these are anthropomorphisms that allow us to relate to them in familiar terms. [Figures of Speech](http://www.cswnet.com/~duxrow/webdoc6.htm#anthropo)

Comment: I'll take the legs from some old table - 
I'll take the arms from some old chair -
I'll take the neck from some old bottle -

And from a horse I'll take the hair -
I'll take the hands and face from some old clock - 
And baby when I'm through -
I'll get more loving from the dumb-dumb-dummy, 
Than I ever got from you (from a song made popular by Louis Armstrong)

Comment: That's great! @Oldbag +1 Love to start the day with an old song ... and a new bottle! :-)